# default concurrency control for sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, concurrency

what is the default concurrency control for SQL Server 2005? Is it optimistic concurrency control or pessimistic concurrency control? Can this be set?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

"Pessimistic" seems to be the default in 2005, although snapshot isolation can be activated if desired:

> In the default pessimistic model, the
>   first writer will block all subsequent
>   writers, but using SI, subsequent
>   writers could actually receive error
>   messages and the application would
>   need to resubmit the original request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917674.aspx